# Flickering CSS Gradient Background on Button Hover

Tags: html, css, transition, linear-gradients

I'm trying to create a smooth transition for a button that has a CSS background gradient, however, it is flickering for me in various browsers (main browser being Chrome), either on the right side of the button, or a white line flickers through it. I haven't been able to find anything that seems to work.

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper container">
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-gradient has-btn-gradient-1">View All Projects</a>
</div>
```

SCSS

```
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.btn {
  &.btn-gradient {
    border-radius: 4.625rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: 0.08em;
    background-color: #0d6efd;
    padding: calc(1.25625rem + 0.075vw) calc(1.2875rem + 0.45vw);
    border-radius: calc(1.5875rem + 4.05vw);
    border: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0.3px 0.7px 1.1px rgb(46 52 68 / 4%),
      1.1px 2.2px 3.6px rgb(46 52 68 / 8%), 1.8px 9px 16px rgb(46 52 68 / 22%);
    box-shadow: 0.3px 0.7px 1.1px rgb(46 52 68 / 4%),
      1.1px 2.2px 3.6px rgb(46 52 68 / 8%), 1.8px 9px 16px rgb(46 52 68 / 22%);
    -webkit-transition: background-size 0.5s, background-size 0.5s,
      -webkit-box-shadow 0.25s, -webkit-transform 0.25s;
    transition: background-size 0.5s, background-size 0.5s,
      -webkit-box-shadow 0.25s, -webkit-transform 0.25s;
    transition: box-shadow 0.25s, transform 0.25s, background-size 0.5s,
      background-size 0.5s;
    transition: box-shadow 0.25s, transform 0.25s, background-size 0.5s,
      background-size 0.5s, -webkit-box-shadow 0.25s, -webkit-transform 0.25s;

    &.has-btn-gradient-1 {
      color: #fff;
      background: linear-gradient(83.1deg, #c850c0 0%, #4158d0 100%),
        linear-gradient(83.1deg, #4158d0 0%, #c850c0 100%);
      background-size: 100% 100%, 0% 100%;
      background-position: 100% 100%, 0 100%;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;

      &:hover {
        background-size: 0% 100%, 100% 100%;
        background-position: 0% 100%, 100% 100%;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -5px, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, -5px, 0);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0.8px 2px rgb(0 0 0 / 7%),
          0px 2.7px 6.7px rgb(0 0 0 / 10%), 0px 12px 20px rgb(0 0 0 / 28%);
        box-shadow: 0px 0.8px 2px rgb(0 0 0 / 7%),
          0px 2.7px 6.7px rgb(0 0 0 / 10%), 0px 12px 20px rgb(0 0 0 / 28%);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have created a codepen demonstrating the problem. https://codepen.io/chrisyerkes/pen/LYdjOqd

It is using bootstrap 5.2 if that helps with debugging.

Comment: only when developer tools are open?

Comment: I see it at all times.

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have found an answer to my own question by fiddling with the code.

I changed the `background:` property to be `background-image:` on the `.has-btn-gradient-1` class instead, and left everything else the same...now no more flicker for me..? I don't really know why that would make a difference, but it seems to have worked for me.

EDIT: Also, this might have been a windows only bug. My friend on osx couldn't see the flicker on my earlier example.

Comment: I didn't see it initially but after opening dev tools the flicker is visible.